# What can be inputted in the following program to access the array?

Tags: c++, exploit

Since `x` is not really validated and is received through scanf, there should be potentially tainted data that can be used to access `bytes`.

Code (not really logically doing anything productive):

```
void getMyBytes(){
    int x, byte;
    int bytes[20];
    scanf("%u %u", &x, &byte);
    bytes[x-1] = byte;
}
```

A known simple (ugly) fix  for this code is:

```
void getMyBytes(){
    int x, byte;
    int bytes[20];
    scanf("%u %u", &x, &byte);
    if (x > sizeof(bytes)/sizeof(*bytes)) return;    --> validation fix
    bytes[x-1] = byte;
}
```

What inputs can I enter in scanf so that I can access `bytes`?

Comment: I don't get your code? In general you should always to bound checking, e.g. negative values and the upper limit (you already did that with the sizeof thing).

Comment: @hellow YES, in general you should always have bound checking. What I'm curious about is what possible inputs could exploit the code.

Comment: `0`, `-1`, `-2`, `-3`, ...

Comment: I actually realized the worst thing a user can do is just to crash the program by just giving an out of bounds input Thanks guys! :)

Comment: The code isn't guaranteed to crash. It's entirely possible that the program keeps running with garbage data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your application but you should always bound check external input when accessing your internal members. How you report this is up to you. But consider using the `std::vector` or `std::array` to help you out. In your example:

```
void getMyBytes(){
    int x, byte;
    std::array<int, 20> bytes; // Bad name btw, an int is very unlikely to be a byte.
    scanf("%u %u", &x, &byte); // scanf is not type safe. Consider using cin <<
    bytes.at(x-1) = byte; // Automatically bound checks for you and will throw an exception
                          // in the case that you are out of bounds. Very useful :)
}
```

[`std::array::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at):

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos, with bounds checking. 
>   If pos is not within the range of the container, an exception of type std::out_of_range is thrown.

Other ways you might report the error include:

1. Hard death in debug: `assert(x >= 0 && x < bytes.size() && "I crashed here because you gave me bad input!")`
2. Error reported to function caller: `if (x < 0 || x > bytes.size()) { return false; }`
3. Throw with more info: `if (x < 0) { throw my_special_underrun_exception; }` and  `if (x > bytes.size()) { throw my_special_overrun_exception; }`

Finally consider visiting the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#slcon3-avoid-bounds-errors) for plenty of tips about how to write good code.

Comment: `std::out_of_range` error does not tell user much, but still better than nothing. `assert` only works in debug builds.

Comment: Thanks @Fantastic Mr Fox

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I doubt the idea is to propogate the `std::out_of_range` all the way to the user. It should be handled by the caller somewhere up the line. And true about assert, i fixed in the question.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox User input errors should always be propagated to the user, so that they fix it easily.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin User of the function as an exception. User of the program as a pop up or something.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox `std::array::at` loses all context and cannot be meaningfully recovered from.

Comment: People argue that `at` method is pretty much useless. If you use it, you know the index may be out of bounds, why don't you check it first and issue a clear message if it is wrong. `std::out_of_range` exception lacks any useful information.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin So 1. `at method is pretty much useless`, that is a pretty sweeping statement for something that is baked into the `std` (for a reason). 2. This is clearly a contrived example. If it was actually something like `getElementAt(size_t pos)` then `at` is fine, it gives you all the information you need. Why? Because the user of the function knows they are accessing a continuous data object and their access was out of bounds (above the length). If it were something like a sparse matrix or where the access to an element is less trivial, then I would tend to agree.

Comment: You assume that you know the definition of function that throws `std::out_of_range`. That is not always true. `at` is useless. Not the first time there is something wrong with C++ standard library.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Correct. That is why in the answer at the very beginning is the nice qualifier: `This depends on your application` followed closely by `How you report this is up to you.` In this example we do know the implementation, because it is contrived.  I will add a 3rd point to the list just for you.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Also with "at is useless", I am going to go ahead and agree with [Herb Sutter and Bjarne Stroustrup](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#slcon3-avoid-bounds-errors) for guidelines on what is useful or not in the standard.